# JSON-Schema, basic sample doesn't validate

Tags: jsonschema

I have this following example schema:

```
{
    "id": "http://schema.acme.com/widgets",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "bentWidget": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["angle", "baseWidget"],                        
            "properties": {
                "angle": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": 0,
                    "maximum": 90
                },
                "baseWidget": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
                }
            }
        },
        "highPowerWidget": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["power", "baseWidget"],            
            "properties": {
                "power": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": 101,
                    "maximum": 200
                },
                "baseWidget": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
                }
            }
        },
        "color": {
            "description": "the color of a widget",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "baseWidget": {
            "description": "The base type for a widget",
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "title",
                "version",
                "colors"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "maximum": 100,
                    "minimum": 1,
                    "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+((_[a-zA-Z]+)*|([a-zA-Z]+_)*|_)"
                },
                "flanged": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                },
                "version": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "maximum": 64,
                    "minimum": 1
                },
                "colors": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/color"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },  

    "anyOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/bentWidget" },
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/highPowerWidget" }
    ]
}
```

and I want to test it, so I write this out to a file:

```
{
    "type": "highPowerWidget",
    "title": "foobar",
    "version": "foo"
}
```

and then I run ajv on it from a shell

```
$ ajv -s widgetSchema.json -d widget-highPower.json 
widget-highPower.json valid
```

And it tells me that it is valid, which is incorrect, a highPowerWidget must have a power property, and the "inherited" version and colors property.

I was able to test my individual schemas by removing the anyOf section and putting in something like this:

```
"properties": {
    "testObject": {
        "type": "object",
        "oneOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/bentWidget" },
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/highPowerWidget" }
        ]
    }
},
"required": [ "testObject" ]
```

and validating this JSON:

```
{
   "testObject": {
        "type" : "highPowerWidget",
        "title" : "title",
        "version" : "baz",
        "colors" : [ "red", "green", "blue"],
        "flanged" : true
   }

}
```

But this seems wrong for two reasons.

1. I shouldn't have to have a "testObject" property
2. The oneOf only worked when I listed a single line, using multiple lines validate anything.

I think I have a basic misunderstanding of how I can write, or at least test, my schemas. My goal is to have an array of objects that all validate, and a set of files which all fail. This way I can unit test my schema.

Comment: power is not a required property of highPowerWidget and thus can be omitted

Comment: Good catch but that's not it. (I created the "widgets" schema from my real work to protect stuff I can't talk about. You're correct, but a highPowerWidget should also have colors and it doesn't have that. Plus when I add required to highPower it still validates...

Comment: (added missing required)

Comment: ahhh, but I am missing '"required": ["power", "baseWidget"],' -- this looks promising...

Comment: wasn't effective..

Answer (score 2):

Your schema is valid.  As written this would be a valid highPowerWidget:

```
{
    "power": 150,
     "baseWidget":{
        "title": "SuperHighPower",
        "flanged":true,
        "version": "version 1",
        "colors":["blue"]
     }   
}
```

I think the misunderstanding is that JSONSchema doesn't support [OO style inheritance](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/348).

Instead this schema is essentially asking for a "baseWidget" property on either the highPowerWidget or bentWidget.  [Here's a sandbox plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWJEUcuRZQvSWD25PX0Q?p=preview) for AJV you can test it with.

**EDIT**: Just thought about it and you could accomplish this removing the baseWidget property from bentWidget and highPowerWidget and instead add `"allOf":[{"$ref":"#/definitions/baseWidget"}]` to each of the subwidgets.  That would require them to pass baseWidget's schema.  So your schema would be:

```
{
  "id": "http://schema.acme.com/widgets",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "bentWidget": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["angle"],
      "properties": {
        "angle": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 0,
          "maximum": 90
        }
      },
      allOf: [{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
      }]
    },
    "highPowerWidget": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["power"],
      "properties": {
        "power": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 101,
          "maximum": 200
        }
      },
      allOf: [{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
      }]
    },
    "color": {
      "description": "the color of a widget",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "baseWidget": {
      "description": "The base type for a widget",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "title",
        "version",
        "colors"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "maximum": 100,
          "minimum": 1,
          "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+((_[a-zA-Z]+)*|([a-zA-Z]+_)*|_)"
        },
        "flanged": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "string",
          "maximum": 64,
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "colors": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "anyOf": [{
    "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
  }, {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/bentWidget"
  }, {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/highPowerWidget"
  }]
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I was away and then the work laptop died. I'm looking at this now. It looks very promising!

Comment: The problem with this method is that it is hard to find JSON data that isn't validated by the schema, and that's not good. For example, set "flanged" to the string "true" and it still validates. We've lost all sense of the the type. I'm going to try and put in a containing object which specifies a typed property, that should do it.

Comment: @PaulCezanne, I've added a possible alternative that would make it more discerning

Comment: @PaulCezanne, sorry I misread the last comment.  Per the ajv sandbox I link to flanged: "true" doesn't validate with the revised schema.  It should fail a type check for boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you have not actually declared a schema for your `"type"` field.  There is nothing in your schema that says that an instance with `"type": "highPoweredWidget"` needs to match the `"#/definitions/highPoweredWidget"` schema.  The names of the schemas under `"definitions"` are only used to locate them for `"$ref"`.  They are not actually used in validation directly.

Since you are using draft-06, you can use the `"const"` keyword to achieve this.  Building on the previous answer, I the following should work:

```
{
  "id": "http://schema.acme.com/widgets",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "bentWidget": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["angle"],
      "properties": {
        "type": {"const": "bentWidget"},
        "angle": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 0,
          "maximum": 90
        }
      },
      allOf: [{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
      }]
    },
    "highPowerWidget": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["power"],
      "properties": {
        "type": {"const": "highPowerWidget"},
        "power": {
          "type": "number",
          "minimum": 101,
          "maximum": 200
        }
      },
      allOf: [{
        "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
      }]
    },
    "color": {
      "description": "the color of a widget",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "baseWidget": {
      "description": "The base type for a widget",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "title",
        "version",
        "colors"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "maximum": 100,
          "minimum": 1,
          "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]+((_[a-zA-Z]+)*|([a-zA-Z]+_)*|_)"
        },
        "flanged": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "version": {
          "type": "string",
          "maximum": 64,
          "minimum": 1
        },
        "colors": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/color"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "anyOf": [{
    "$ref": "#/definitions/baseWidget"
  }, {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/bentWidget"
  }, {
    "$ref": "#/definitions/highPowerWidget"
  }]
}
```

This will ensure that if your *instance* has a `"type": "highPowerWidget"` then it will have a "power" property.

I did not add a `"const"` type field for "baseWidget", so it will match any type, which seems correct as far as I can tell.

Note that in draft-07 (published on Monday and I think supported by a beta build of ajv) you can use `"if"` `"then"`, and `"else"` keywords to make this more explicit.